# Change tableview content offset for reload animation

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

In my application I am using a TableView behind a completely transparent navigationBar. 
To achieve this I am setting the top contentInset of the Tableview to -64 for all devices except the iPhone X. For the iPhone X I am setting this value to -88.

My problem is that when I am using the tableView's pull to refresh function the refreshControl is for half shown behind the tableView because the content offset for the refreshControl to be completely shown is -64.

How can I tackle that problem? Is there a possibility to tell the tableView on which contentOffset to start the refresh animation and on which contentOffset to end?

[image]